# How do I show the percentage of a group in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to show the percentage of tasks completed before a certain deadline, for separate groups.

I have calculated the percentage for the whole, but when I try to split the data into a calculation for each group I keep getting errors.

**To calculate the percentage, I have been using:**

```
    DECLARE @TM DATETIME;
    SET @TM = DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,'19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')

    SELECT CAST(
        (
        SELECT COUNT (a.[completed]) 
        FROM [table] a 
        JOIN [other table] b 
        ON a.TaskID = b.TaskID 
        WHERE a.[completed] >= DATEADD(MONTH,0,@TM) AND 
              b.[completedByDeadline] = 1) AS DECIMAL (10,2))
            /
        CAST(
        (
        SELECT COUNT([completed]) 
        FROM [table]
        WHERE [completed] >= DATEADD(MONTH,0,@TM))
        *100 AS Decimal (10,2))
```

When I try to add the `[groupName]` column to the SELECT list and a GROUP BY clause, there are errors; it mentions the need for an EXISTS keyword, but I can't see where to put one.

Any help that people could provide would be fantastic! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use this:

```
DECLARE @TM DATETIME;
SET @TM = DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,'19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')

SELECT 
    COUNT (case 
               when b.[completedByDeadline] = 1 
                   then 1 
               else NULL 
           end) / COUNT (a.[completed])
FROM [table] a 
    LEFT JOIN [other table] b 
        ON a.TaskID = b.TaskID 
WHERE a.[completed] >= DATEADD(MONTH,0,@TM)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using `AVG()` for this sort of query:

```
SELECT AVG(case when b.[completedByDeadline] = 1 then 1.0 else 0 
           end) 
FROM [table] a LEFT JOIN
     [other table] b 
      ON a.TaskID = b.TaskID 
WHERE a.[completed] >= DATEADD(MONTH, 0, @TM);
```

If `completedByDeadline` only takes on the values `0` and `1`, this can be simplified further:

```
SELECT AVG(b.[completedByDeadline] * 1.0)
FROM [table] a LEFT JOIN
     [other table] b 
      ON a.TaskID = b.TaskID 
WHERE a.[completed] >= DATEADD(MONTH, 0, @TM);
```

Note that these will return `NULL` if there are no corresponding tasks in `b`.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I managed to get it working using Radu's answer but I checked out your method too, and will save it for future use!